# ngModel needs $parent when within Transcluded html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive for a input field that uses transclusion to take the elements that are enclosed in the directives element which includes an `ng-model` attribute.  After reading countless SO questions and Angular documentation to find out how to get the `ng-model` in the transcluded html to sync with the `ng-model` in my directive I finally stumbled stumbled upon a trick to get it to work.  That is to use `$parent` where the `ng-model` is within the input field.  This is all fine and dandy, however, it seems clunky/hackish.

Plunker shown here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gEje6Z2uuTs9DFPeCZfv

I tried to make this a little more elegant by messing around with the transclusion function within my link function like so:

```

```
      var transcludedContent, transclusionScope;

      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        //headerCtrl.$element.append(clone);
        transcludedContent = clone;
        transclusionScope = scope;

        console.log('scope form: ', scope);
        console.log('transclude form: ', clone);


      });
```

```

Also, shown in this Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/11k9LiA5hyi4xydWBo3H?p=preview

One would think that the transclusion function would allow you to overwrite the transclusion scope with the scope of your directive then the `ng-model` attributes would be associated and bound to the directives scope, however, this is not the case.

Although, the `$parent.<ng-model>` does work, it seems very hackish, and can lead to bugs like if my directive was not used with a parent scope that doesnt have an `account` object defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing that.

1) Exposing the `account` variable using `=`

http://plnkr.co/edit/DxsipWRj0AJe6Yi3bhse

JS:

```
app.directive('formControl', [function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>{{account.name}}',
      scope: {
        account: '='
      },
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.account={};

        console.log('SCOPE: ', scope)
      }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<form-control account='account'>
  <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
  <input name="name" ng-model="account.name" \>
</form-control>
```

2) Using `transclude` function:

This is similar to what `ngIf` and `ngRepeat` do. `ngRepeat` actually decorates every scope with `$index` and similar values, the same way you want to decorate your scope with `account`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cZjWqIgO23nzc0kMZA57

JS:

```
app.directive('formControl', ['$animate', function($animate){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: 'element',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
        //this creates a new scope that inherits from the parent scope
        //that new scope will be what you'll be working with inside your
        //transcluded html
        transclude(function (clone, scope) {
          scope.account = {name:'foobar'};
          $animate.enter(clone, null, element);

          console.log('SCOPE: ', scope)
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<form-control>
  <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
  <input name="name" ng-model="account.name" \><br>
  {{account.name}}
</form-control>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation.  I wonder why you cant use an isolate scope then assign that scope to the transclude function.  One would think that the `ng-model=account` originally defined in the html and assigned to parent scope would then be assigned to the isolate scope of the directive.  This could be useful when you want to completely use a `brand new` untouched scope.

Comment: You could call ``transclude(scope.$new(true), function (...) {...})``